# csv Writer using Datafields returned by Pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

Hello I'm working on a project that reads an excel worksheet, collects columns of data based on header title, and then writes that data to a much leaner csv file which I'll be using for more fun later.

I'm getting a syntax error while trying to write my new csv file, I think it has something to do with the datafields I'm using to get my columns in pandas.

I'm new to Python so any help you can provide would be great, thanks!

```
import pandas
import xlrd
import csv


def csv_from_excel():

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Python27\\Work\\spreadsheet.xlsx")
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    spoofingFile = open('spoofing.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(spoofingFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    spoofingFile.close()

csv_from_excel()
df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python27\\Work\\spoofing.csv')

time = df["InviteTime (Oracle)"]
orignum = df["Orig Number"]
origip = df["Orig IP Address"]
destnum = df["Dest Number"]

sheet0bj = csv.writer(open("complete.csv", "wb")
sheet0bj.writerow([time,orignum,origip,destnum])
```

The syntax error is thus:

```
file c:\python27\work\formatsheettest.py, line36
sheet0bj.writerow([time, orignum, origip, destnum])
       ^
Syntax error: Invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing paren on the second to last line.
`sheet0bj = csv.writer(open("complete.csv", "wb")`
should be
`sheet0bj = csv.writer(open("complete.csv", "wb"))`

I assume you've figured that out by now, though.